# Understanding &lt and &gt

Tags: android, xml

I'm looking [this site](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/).
I can't understand what this means:

```
private ArrayList&lt;HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;&gt; data;
```

Please, explain this to me.

Thanks

Comment: In short answer: Just replace `&lt;` with **<** and `&gt;` with **>**.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Those are html entities:

```
&lt; -> <
&gt; -> >
```

Those characters have to be escaped in html because they are used to start and end html tags:

```
<p>, <b>, etc.
```

So the string you asked about, with html entities replaced, is:

```
Private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
```

Those html entities were left in the code snippet on the site you mentioned, most likely by mistake or else due to a bug in how that site escapes code snippets.

Comment: +1. When reading the answer consider "HTML" replaced with "XML" (if your question relates to XML).

Comment: sorry to post same, but at the time of posting i didn't got answer notification!

Answer (score 1):

That is blog post error in HTML encoding,

- `&lt;` = `<` (Less than)
- `&gt;` = `>` (Greaterthan)

Code should actually look like `private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;`

You should be able to decode such HTML Encoding from [here (htmlspecialchars_decode).](http://htmlspecialchars_decode.onlinephpfunctions.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It's Generic templates that also java supports. Think that without Generics how you can declare such a thing like this.

It might be like this:

```
HashMap table = new HashMap();

ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

arr.Add(table);
```

With Generics, instead of working with objects and casting or converting (late-bounding), you can write is as easy as possible. Like you mentioned:

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
```

and work with the declared variable so easier.

Cheers